# Extract .cpgz file with Python

Tags: python-2.7, archive

On my mac I've create an archive file `archived_dir.cpgz` using the native macOS Archive Utility tool. The contents of this file are the following:

```
/
   myFile.java
   /dir
       myOtherFile.java
       oneMoreFile.java
   MANIFEST.MF
```

I need a way to extract the contents of this archive using python.  I've tried using the `Zipfile` lib, the `pyunpack` library, and the `patool` library (amongst others).  Using these tools seems to extract the contents of the `.cpgz` file as a single file having the contents of all 4 files (not really useable).

Using the macOS Archive Utility tool to extract the `archied_dir.cpgz` file extracts the contents as expected.

What would be the best way to extract the contents of an archvied_dir.cpgz using Python 2.7?

**NOTE:** I'm not getting the cpgz->zip->cpgz issue, the Archive Utility works as expected.